# Visual Glitch Using dynamic-data in Chosen with bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

Using bootstrap Version 2.1.1
Using last chosen

I'm experimenting a visual glitch when the chosen is redered inside a tab's content, creating a blank space inside the tab content div and a scroll bar.

Jquery Code

```
$('.chzn-select').chosen();
    <?php if(!empty($data_which_depends_the _chosen)){ ?>
     $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo(site_url("/url_to_get_the_data/")); ?>',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            l: <?php echo($data_which_depends_the _chosen); ?>,
            <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>'
        },
        success: setChosenOptions
    });
    <?php } ?>
```

...

```
var setChosenOptions = function(data)
{
    $("select[name='numChosen[]']").children().remove();
    if(data !== null)
    {
        $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
            <?php if(!$readOnly){ ?>
            $("select[name='numChosen[]']").append('<option value="' + item.ids + '">' + item.number + '</option>');
            <?php }else{ ?>
            $("select[name='numChosen[]']").append('<option disabled="disabled" value="' + item.ids + '">' + item.number + '</option>');
            <?php } ?>
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo(site_url("/url_to_get_other_data/")); ?>',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                l: '<?php echo($data_which_depends_the _chosen); ?>',
                <?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name()?>: '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash()?>'
            },
            success: function(data){
                if(data !== null)
                {
                    $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
                        if($("select[name='numChosen[]']").find("option[value=" + item.ids + "]").length)
                            $("select[name='numChosen[]']").find("option[value=" + item.ids + "]").attr('selected','selected');
                        else
                            $("select[name='numChosen[]']").append('<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" value="' + item.ids + '">' + item.number + '</option>');
                    });
                }
                $("select[name='numChosen[]']").trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
        });                 
    }
}
```

all the problem occurs when `$("select[name='numChosen[]']").trigger("liszt:updated");` is called and this is how it looks:

[image]

the question is: any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply added `style="overflow: visible;"` to the `<div class="tab-content" style="overflow: visible;">` and problem solved :D